# People's God and Real God

Tags: gods

Let's imagine a world where all people prayers and beliefs create some paranormal entities - just the way people imagine them in some paranormal realm. So people believe in God and through thousands of years generate this "people's God" as some creature that becomes powerful, that really answers prayers, interferes with daily life etc, etc - gaining energy from all the thoughts and imagination of its followers.

Now let's imagine that this world indeed had a REAL God that created it. This God who doesn't need any power from people, because he already is too powerful before the creation of the world.

Now, what will be the relations between this people's god and God? Will the last one gradually become redundant?

Comment: By what mechanism do the people create their own god? If the one god gets his power from prayer, where do the 'real' god get his powers from? Can't answer the questions without this information.

Comment: The real one was powerful without any follower's. And can operate on its own.

Comment: I believe this question is too broad and primarily opinion-based as any answer is as good as any other. The gods could become allies, enemies, ignore each other, be unable to interact at all, etc. and it would all be plausible based on the description, or lack of, provided.

Comment: @SergZ. But how? If there is no 'how' then this question is just opinion based.

Comment: I believe this is what they call story based. It depends on the characters, their history, your intentions and so on

Comment: @Raditz_35 Perhaps you should re-read the criteria for Too Story-based. This doesn't depend on the actions of a story. The deities in question are elements of a world. One with deities, as such things can be considered conceptually.

Comment: So you've read Pratchett - but not quite enough.  Go read the Science of Discworld series :)

Comment: I didn't read Pratchett. It was just an idea out of nowhere. :) Or to be more precise - I tried to read several of his things (not connected with this topic) but found him kinda boring.

Answer (score 4):

It mostly depends on how you characterize the real God.
Is it interested in mortal affairs? Is it benign or malign? Does it care for free will? What are its thoughts about the "people's god"? Does its power rely on faith, or is it in fixed amounts?

From your question, you state that:

> Now let's imagine that this world indeed had a REAL God that created it. This God who doesn't need any power from people, because he already is too powerful before the creation of the world.

I'm assuming here that the original god, since its responsible for the whole creation, is somewhat aware that people beliefs can materialize into paranormal entities. Being an entity of limitless power, he isn't interested in the whole procedure.

But then again, from your description of the facts, your original god must be quite the absent one. The people's god get following because it actually interferes with ordinary life - hence, we must assume that the real one does not.

Since the original one seemed uninterested from the start, there is a good chance it will remain so. Depending on how much powerful you make it, it may even be so out of reach than the other god isn't a threat to it.

Or maybe, the original god is following some grand scheme of things, limiting its intervention in subtler, less noticeable ways. For example, the original god may be willing to talk only to the purest of human being, on of the likes that is born every millenia. Or it may consider unethical to directly speak to mortals, not wanting to tamper their mind with his divine wisdom and omnipotency. In short, if the original god is following some sort of code of conduct, it isn't likely that it will break it without a good reason.

Now, a good reason could be that the people's god may be perceived as "*absolute evil*®", or its presence may be an offense to the original god. If this happens, you have to ask yourself how the power scaling works in your world. 
Maybe the original one is very powerful, but only in some aspects (it can create the world) but lacking in others (it can't alter human minds). 
Maybe the original one is omnipotent, but the people's god power escalates exponentially for every new believer. The original one may send packs of his angels (or other kinds of emissaries) to deal with the people's god, but this in turn could rally more believer to his side (let's remember that the people's god is the one answering prayers, after all).

So, you've got yourself quite a good deal of possibilities.